# How to pivot tables with duplicate entries? Order matters

Tags: python, pandas, exploratory-data-analysis

I have a Pandas DataFrame in Python such as this:

```
       Group     Pre/post    Value
0         A        Pre         3
1         A        Pre         5
2         A        Post       13
3         A        Post       15
4         B        Pre         7
5         B        Pre         8  
6         B        Post       17
7         B        Post       18
```

And I'd like to turn it into a different table such as:

```
      Group       Pre      Post
0       A       3         13
1       A       5         15
2       B       7         17
3       B       8         18
```

I tried pivoting with `df.pivot(index='Group', columns='Pre/post', values='Value')` but since I have repeated values and order is important, it went traceback

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it, use list as an aggfunc in [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html?highlight=pivot_table#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table), to collect the duplicate values for index and column as a list, then using [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html?highlight=explode#pandas.DataFrame.explode) split the list into multiple rows.

```
df.pivot_table(index='Group', columns='Pre/post', values='Value', aggfunc=list
              ).reset_index().explode(['Post','Pre'], ignore_index=True)
```

```
Pre/post    Group   Post    Pre
      0         A     13    3
      1         A     15    5
      2         B     17    7
      3         B     18    8
```

Comment: This seems like an inefficient way to handle the duplicates ;) The canonical way would be `df.assign(idx=df.groupby('Pre/post').cumcount()).pivot(index=['idx', 'Group'], columns='Pre/post', values='Value')`

Comment: Yes @mozway, I agree